# Routing and Docker

Tags: linux, сеть, docker

Добрый день! На системе Debian установлен сервис docker 17.12.1-ce и имеются 2 интерфейса с одинаковыми gateway в одной сети, работающих через 2 таблицы описанных в /etc/iptoute2/rt_tables - T1, T2:

```
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.10.6.2
  netmask 255.255.252.0

  # hook scripts
  post-up ip route add default via '10.10.6.1' dev eth0 table T1
  post-up ip rule add from '10.10.6.2' table T1
  post-up ip rule add to '10.10.6.2' table T1
  post-up ip route add default via '10.10.6.1' metric 101 dev eth0
  post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table T1
  post-down ip rule del from 0/0 to 0/0 table T1
```

второй интерфейс настроен аналогично, при поднятии образа докера поднимается мост docker0 и в системе добавляется маршрут:

```
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
```

и из докера наружу ходят все пакеты нормально, за исключением интерфейсов хоста: eth0 и eth1, на ip адреса этих интерфейсов пакеты пропадают сразу после 172.17.0.1. На ip докера все пакеты тоже проходят нормально. Решение добавить маршрут в таблицу

```
ip route add 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 table T1
```

Вопросы:

1. насколько это правильное решение?
2. как сделать так чтобы при поднятии бриджа сервис докера сам добавлял нужный маршрут?

Comment: руль неправильный

Comment: Побольше информации можно? что конкретно неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что роутинг рулес работают до ната. Тоесть пакеты имеют адреса 172.17.0.0. В Ваших рулях маршрут выбирается из адреса источника. Такая маршрутизация работает шорошо только на трафике от хоста, но не проходящем.

Вариант решения классический: разметить соединения и пакеты в мангле, маршрутизировать по метке.

Вариант продвинутый - сделать один и тот же адрес на оба интерфейса, пошаманить с арптаблес и маршрутом прописать мультихоп (мультипаф) - два шлюза в одном маршруте. Хотя можно оставить 2 адреса и включить маскарад.

Comment: Спасибо, нужно время чтобы проверить! но тогда 2 вопроса попутно как пакет находит маршрут если я прописываю правило конкретно в таблице? тогда все работает корректно, ведь я адрес источника не меняю в этом случае. И второй вопрос 1 ip-адрес на 2 интерфейса это вообще как? поясните примером пожалуйста

Comment: Докер создает правило для нат, если делаешь через expose. Адрес источника меняется через коннтрак когда пакет проходит обратно к клиенту.

Comment: Оставь два, а то локалка запутается.

Comment: Проверил цепочки в nat iptables вроде как все верно они есть и работают, буду тогда пробовать через мангл размечать и маршрутизировать пакеты по метке. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Добрался до конфигурации параметров сети, ввиду отсутствия сложных манипуляций с трафиком и граблей с правилами роутинга после создания таблиц пришел к инересному заключению, все правила свелись к

```
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.10.6.2
  netmask 255.255.252.0    
  # hook scripts
  post-up ip route add default via '10.10.6.1' metric 101 dev eth0
```

И аналогичной конфигурации eth1. И все пингуется и работает: из докера пакеты доходят, до него тоже, при отключении eth0 трафик идет через eth1 и при отключении eth1 трафик идет через eth0.

Есть минусы у данного варианта решения?